# RegExp replace after

Tags: regex, insert, replace

I have some link templates and I need to replace substrings inside of that links.
Link templates:

1. "/all_news"
2. "/all_news/"
3. "/all_news/page1"
4. "/all_news/page1/"

All of these templates mean the same thing - first page of news page without filtering.

So I need to:

1st template - insert "/pageX"

2nd template - insert "pageX"

3rd and 4th templates - replace page number

Is it possible with only one regexp?

If yes, then please help me.

If no, then I have 2nd question:
maybe its possible to replace everything after "/all_news" on "/pageX"?

I mean next logic:

1. string started
2. ok, I see substring "/all_news"
3. I replace everything after "/all_news" even if nothing exist(if string ends by "/all_news")
4. I return "/all_news/pageX".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This'll do it.

```
'/all_news/page1'.replace(/(.*\/all_news).*/,'$1' + '/pageX');
```

Just one for all.

Java has lookbehind. It negates the need for the $1. The solution looks like:

```
String result = "/all_news/page1";
String pattern = "(?<=\\/all_news).*";
System.out.println(result.replaceAll(pattern,"/PageX"));
```

Cheers.

Comment: You didn't say which language... this is JavaScript. But the regex /(.*\/all_news).*/  should be usable anywhere (with only minor alterations) and the $1 construct too. Additionally all major languages have similar replace functions.

Comment: awwwww...lol...Ive chosen the hard way but it was easier than I thought

Comment: Yes, I'm glad you like it :) If it _really_ works... (as I can never be sure) do you reckon you could find the time to tick the answer?

Comment: it works but I thought that "/all_news" wont be touched. I thought its possible to define substring without it's replacement.

Comment: You won't lose "/all_news" in the replacement - that's what the $1 does - if you don't want to use $1 you can use lookaheads - or lookbehinds even. Is there trouble with using $1?

Comment: as I understand using backrefs is the same as variables? if yes then its a bit slower than replacing only part you need to replace

Comment: You can do it with "lookbehind". But not without... as far as I can tell.

Comment: Ok mate. I put one up that uses Lookbehind and no $1 references. It will work in Java and maybe others - but _not_ javascript. And again, if it's all good go ahead and tick the answer :) good luck

Comment: No worries bro. all the best

Comment: oh, i forgot to say, i need it for PHP(servers care about every ms of time:) ) in JS I'll use your solution :)